# Blackjack game - How to use the getter and the toString() methods

Tags: java, for-loop, switch-statement, tostring, getter

I'm trying to learn Java and I copied a program that simulate a blackjack game (from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=buGFs1aQgaY).

I understood most of it but I got stuck at how the program make the sum of an hand. In the forth class, called "Player", at some point there is:

cardNum = this.hand[c].getNumber();

Let's say that:

this.hand[c] = King of Clubs.

I don't understand how the program gives as a result:

cardNum = 13.

How does the getNumber method works? (The method is made in the first class, called Card)

I'll post all the classes of the program.

FIRST CLASS.

```
public class Card {
    private Suit mySuit;
    private int myNumber;

    public Card(Suit aSuit, int aNumber){

        this.mySuit = aSuit;

        if (aNumber >= 1 && aNumber <= 13){
            this.myNumber = aNumber;
    }   else{
            System.err.println(aNumber + " is not a valid Card number");
            System.exit(1);
        }}

    public int getNumber(){
        return myNumber;

    }

    public String toString(){
        String numStr = "Err";


        switch(this.myNumber){

            case 2:
                numStr = "Two";
                break;
            case 3:
                numStr = "Three";
                break;
            case 4:
                numStr = "Four";
                break;
            case 5:
                numStr = "Five";
                break;
            case 6:
                numStr = "Six";
                break;
            case 7:
                numStr = "Seven";
                break;
            case 8:
                numStr = "Eight";
                break;
            case 9:
                numStr = "Nine";
                break;
            case 10:
                numStr = "Ten";
                break;
            case 11:
                numStr = "Jack";
                break;
            case 12:
                numStr = "Queen";
                break;
            case 13:
                numStr = "King";
                break;
            case 1:
                numStr = "Ace";
                break;


        }
        return numStr + " of " + mySuit.toString();

    }

}
```

SECOND CLASS

```
public enum Suit {
    Clubs,
    Diamonds,
    Spades,
    Hearts
}
```

THIRD CLASS

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Deck {

    private Card[] myCards;
    private int numCards;

    public Deck(){
        this(1,false);

    }

    public Deck(int numDecks, boolean shuffle) {

        this.numCards = numDecks * 52;
        this.myCards = new Card[this.numCards];

        int c = 0;
        for (int d = 0; d < numDecks; d++) {
            for (int s = 0; s < 4; s++) {
                for (int n = 1; n <= 13; n++) {
                    this.myCards[c] = new Card(Suit.values()[s], n);
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (shuffle) {
            this.shuffle();
        }
    }

    public void shuffle(){

        Random rng = new Random();

        Card temp;

        int j;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.numCards; i++){

            j = rng.nextInt(this.numCards);
            temp = this.myCards[i];
            this.myCards[i] = this.myCards[j];
            this.myCards[j] = temp;
        }
    }


    public Card dealNextCard() {

        Card top = this.myCards[0];
        for (int c = 1; c < this.numCards; c++) {
            this.myCards[c - 1] = this.myCards[c];
        }

        this.myCards[this.numCards - 1] = null;

        this.numCards--;

        return top;
    }

    public void printDeck(int numToPrint){
        for(int c=0; c < numToPrint; c++) {
            System.out.printf("% 3d/%d/%s\n", c + 1, this.numCards,
                    this.myCards[c].toString());
        }
            System.out.printf("/t/t[%d other]\n", this.numCards-numToPrint);




    }
}
```

FORTH CLASS

```
public class Player {

    private String name;

    private Card[]hand = new Card[10];
    private int numCards;

    public Player(String aName) {
        this.name = aName;
        this.emptyHand();
    }
    public void emptyHand(){


        for(int c=0; c<10; c++){
            this.hand[c] = null;
        }
        this.numCards = 0;
    }

    public boolean addCard(Card aCard) {
        if (this.numCards == 10) {
            System.err.printf("%s's hand already has 10 cards;" +
                    "cannot add another\n", this.name);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        this.hand[this.numCards] = aCard;
        this.numCards++;

        return(this.getHandSum()<= 21);
    }

    public int getHandSum(){

        int handSum = 0;
        int cardNum;
        int numAces = 0;

        for(int c=0; c < this.numCards; c++) {

            cardNum = this.hand[c].getNumber();

            if (cardNum == 1) {
                numAces++;
                handSum += 11;
            } else if (cardNum > 10) {
                handSum += 10;
            } else {
                handSum += cardNum;
            }
            }


    while (handSum >21 && numAces > 0){
        handSum -= 10;
        numAces--;
    }

    return handSum;

    }

    public void printHand(boolean showFirstCard){
    System.out.printf("%s's cards:\n", this.name);
    for(int c=0; c<this.numCards; c++) {
    if(c==0 && !showFirstCard) {
        System.out.println(" [hidden]");
    } else {
        System.out.printf(" %s\n", this.hand[c].toString());
    }
    }

        }


}
```

FIFTH CLASS - PROGRAM

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameRunner{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Deck theDeck = new Deck(1, true);

        theDeck.printDeck(52);

        Player me = new Player("Player 1");
        Player dealer = new Player("Dealer");

        me.addCard(theDeck.dealNextCard());
        dealer.addCard(theDeck.dealNextCard());
        me.addCard(theDeck.dealNextCard());
        dealer.addCard(theDeck.dealNextCard());

        System.out.println("Cards are dealt\n");
        me.printHand(true);
        dealer.printHand(false);
        System.out.println("\n");

        boolean meDone = false;
        boolean dealerDone = false;
        String ans;

        while(!meDone || !dealerDone) {

            if(!meDone){
                System.out.println("Hit or Stay? (Enter H or S):");
                ans = sc.next();
                System.out.println();

                if(ans.compareToIgnoreCase("H") == 0) {
                    meDone = !me.addCard(theDeck.dealNextCard());
                    me.printHand(true);
                } else {
                    meDone = true;

                }
            }

            if(!dealerDone){
                if (dealer.getHandSum() < 17) {
                    System.out.println("The Dealer hits\n");
                    dealerDone = !dealer.addCard(theDeck.dealNextCard());
                    dealer.printHand(false);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("The Dealer stays\n");
                    dealerDone = true;
                }
            }

        System.out.println();

        }
        sc.close();
        me.printHand(true);
        dealer.printHand(true);

        int mySum = me.getHandSum();
        int dealerSum = dealer.getHandSum();

        if(mySum > dealerSum && mySum <= 21 || dealerSum>21) {
            System.out.println("Your win");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Dealer wins!");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create each instance of class `Card`, you pass in a Suit and a **VALUE** for that card:

```
... = new Card(Suit.values()[s], n);
```

In the above example from the code, the `n` variable is the value of the card, and was going from 1 to 13 because of the `for` loops setup to create the decks of cards.

In the **Constructor** for class `Card`, we then store that value in the private member called `myNumber` seen below:

```
public class Card {

    private Suit mySuit;
    private int myNumber; // <-- the value of the card is stored here

    public Card(Suit aSuit, int aNumber){
        // ... other code ...
        this.myNumber = aNumber; // <-- store the passed in value in the instance member
        // ... other code ...
    }

}
```

Finally, the `getNumber()` function simply returns the stored value of the card, previously put into `myNumber`:

```
public int getNumber(){
    return myNumber;

}
```

Comment: Ok, I wasn't thinking about the fact the each card is an object. But, is it possible to access all the card objects along with the "myNumber" associated to them. Like in an array (or better, like with enumerate in Python). I'm trying to find a way to show how the data is structured in order to understand it better.

Comment: Sure...but it really depends on **WHERE** you're trying to access the instances from.  Since we are dealing with classes, the only members that can be seen from **outside** the classes, are **public** members.  If you're **inside** the class, however, then you can access whatever you like from that class.